# how do I kill bosses?

Tags: empire-defense-2

Undead Yahua and other Undead bosses take 10 lifes of my hero, but are hardly damaged by my troops. I use witches, archers, hammer soldiers and crossbows, all of them level 5. X Liu Bei is on level 15, with a Fire Fan and  Flying Sand (all soldiers rend armor +20%)

As far as I remember I had no problem with them when I used taoist Priests. Are these bosses especially vulnerable to lighning, and immune to everything else?

These bosses only come in the arena.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plan your route carefully so Liu Bei's 4-way special attack could cover most or all of the road. A typical road plan looks like this:

```
--\ /--\  .......................
/-/ | /-/ ....................... Liu
\---/ \- ........................\   \
Soldier Soldier                  | /-|
Soldier Soldier                  | \-\
Soldier Soldier                  \ _ /
```

Hammer and catapult work best on this kind of road plan because of their area attack. You also need crossbow for air attack and gold miners to get economics going. Priests are versatile but too expensive compared to their range and damages.

Delay the enemy's advance (and death) with witches and axe man so you can have special attacks for the next wave - or for the current wave if you still got too many enemies left. If you got enough money, buy good cloth that heals the HP over time.

Answer (score 1):

Undead bosses have a extremely high hp. Witches alone is not enough, you need to level up your axeman at least lvl10 or better to increase it probability of stun.

Even now I'm using x. zhao yun max lvl, upgraded regulus sword, zombie spearman(critical rate +30000 per hit) still having hard time to kill this undead at it 4th appearance (27 or 28th wave I forgot :-).

Plan your route and stun him!!